# Qt OpenGL data synchronization / Model/View implementation

Tags: qt, opengl, qt-creator, model-view, qt5.5

I am trying to develop an application with Qt 5.5 and OpenGL. The basic work of the application will be to load simple objects, modify their positions in a scene and save them together with other attributes (material, name, parents/child relations etc...).

The only thing I am struggling about for a week now is that I really don't know how I should take on the problem of synchronizing data. Let's say I have some kind of SceneGraph class which takes care of all SceneObjects. Those SceneGraphs should be rendered in a SceneView-Widget which can be used to modify it's Objects via transformations. Now how would I tell every SceneView that an Object changed it's position?

I thought of the Model/View architecture for a moment but I am not really sure how this implementation should look like.

What would be the best way to handle Objects like that in different Windows/Widgets but still have one single piece of data?

- SceneObject:

  - Holds the mesh-information (verticies, uvs, etc..)
  - Has a name (QString)
  - Has a material
  - Has a transform storing position, rotation and scaling information
    (Important: these datatypes should be synchronized in all views)
- SceneGraph:

  - Contains different SceneObjects and is passed to SceneViews
- SceneView:

  - The QWidget responsible for drawing the Scene correctly in any QWindow.
  - Has it's own camera to move around.
  - Handles UserInput and allows transformation of SceneObjects.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the signal and slot to observe position updates of SceneObjects and process them in SceneView.